# Counting and filtering based on it, inside an xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a source XML generated automatically by a clumsy program, which contains repeated and empty entries.

I want to be able to select and show ONLY the entry the most represented, filtering the empty entries. For example, suppose my source XML is

```
<catalog>
    <letter>
      <char>A</char>
    </letter>
    <letter>
        <char>B</char>
    </letter>
    <letter>
        <char></char>
    </letter>
    <letter>
        <char>A</char>
    </letter>
    <letter>
        <char></char>
    </letter>
    <letter>
        <char></char>
    </letter>
</catalog>
```

Then, I want to get only A.

I can do:

```
<table><tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/letter[char!='']">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="char" /></td>
  </xsl:for-each>
</tr></table>
```

which will show me a table containing only A, B, A (not the empty columns).

Now I want to get only A, because it is the one that appears most often. How do I do it?

**Update**

Here is an attempt, which does not work.

```
<xsl:variable name="counter" select="0" />
<xsl:variable name="this" select="" />
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/letter[char!='']">
  <xsl:variable name="var" select="char" />
  <xsl:variable name="cou" select="count(/catalog/letter[char=$var])" />
  <xsl:if test="$cou &gt; counter">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="$var" />
  </xsl:if>
<td><xsl:value-of select="$this" /></td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to mention is that in XSLT that variables are immutable. They cannot be changed once set, so if were trying to have a "counter" variable, it would not work.

To fix your current XSLT you could use the `xsl:sort` command for the `xsl:for-each` to sort on the number of `letter` elements with the same `char`, and then just pick the first one. Like

```
  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/letter[char!='']">
     <xsl:sort select="count(/catalog/letter[char=current()/char])" order="descending" />
     <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

This, however, is very inefficient because you will be repeatedly be counting the same nodes over and over again.

A better technique is to use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), which involves defining a key to look up the elements

```
<xsl:key name="letter" match="letter[char!='']" use="char" />
```

You then use this key to find each distinct letter, and also to count the number of letters with the same char.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="letter" match="letter[char!='']" use="char" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/letter[generate-id() = generate-id(key('letter', char)[1])]">
         <xsl:sort select="count(key('letter', char))" order="descending" />
         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output just `A`.